# ODP.Net Unmanged x64 causes unhandled exception

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, odac

for the past few years I have been using the Unmanaged driver for Oracle, the 32bit `Version=4.121.2.0` from October 2015

Now I am trying to upgrade to use the new Oracle client and use the 64bit `Version=4.122.18.3`
When I try to connect to the database I get an error that seems to not be handled inside the Oracle assembly, and this makes it very hard to determine what the problem is.

I then tried to use the previous version instead `Version=4.122.1.0` with x64 and I also get the same Error.

Any Ideas how to get this working or determine what the problem is will be much appreciated.

Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

StackTrace:

```
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable, OracleLogicalTransaction m_OracleLogicalTransaction)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src, OracleLogicalTransaction m_oracleLogicalTransaction)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionOCP.Open(OracleConnection con)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
```

I have the following config oracle related config setup in my project:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="ProFemOnline.Data.Old.ProFemDbModelOldConfiguration, ProFemOnline.Data.Old">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Did you also update the Oracle Client?

Comment: Did you change compile/run options? Your application must run in 64-bit mode if you like to use the 64-bit Oracle driver

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, Update to the latest version, but like I said, on the older version I get the same error.
Yes, its set to run in 64bit. If you don't set that you can't even run the app. The app is running, but the error happens when trying to execute a query.

Comment: Then please show us the code where you get the exception. From the stack it looks like you get the exception when you try to open the connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "Update to the latest version". The version of the Oracle Client must be **exactly(!)** the same version as the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proabaly a late reply, but I got same issue

```
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()
```

and fixed by :

copying the **oraons.dll** from oracle_home to oracle_home\bin folder

e.g.
from

```
"C:\oracle\odac\oraons.dll"
```

to

```
"C:\oracle\odac\bin\oraons.dll"
```

if you have both oracle client and ODAC installed then copy from ODAC home to ODAC\bin folder

Comment: This worked for me. Apparently the issue is with the setting "DLLPath" in the "HKLM\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET" Registry key.  Particularly troublesome if full client and ODAC are together (not sure why you'd do that). ODAC/client are pretty much separate, except each of their ODP impls share that key. So "DLLPath" is supposed to be where the regular (Instant Client) DLLs live; for ODAC though, this denotes where the Oracle Provider Service  DLL ("OraOpsnn.dll") lives, which is actually in the "bin" folder.  So "DLLPath" can't represent both it and "oraons.dll" (2 separate folders in ODAC).